# godep save ./... gives an error - godep: Unable to find SrcRoot for package

Tags: go, dependencies, lib, godeps

When I run `godep save ./...` from the root directory of the project I'm getting the following error. Any clues what might I have to fix?

> godep: Unable to find SrcRoot for package .

Comment: Getting the same error.

Comment: @AurelBílý: Th go tool uses `...` as a path wildcard

Comment: @Pubudu: Is you source properly located in GOPATH? Can you build your package by its import path?

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem location matters a lot in Go. You’re expected to be running things from a designated ‘gopath’, but don’t confuse gopath with the location of go (don’t just set it to where go is installed).

Your gopath should be a location that you’re happy to put your go source code for the foreseeable future. I’ve set mine to /Users/ejiro/go.

```
cat <<END >> ~/.bashrc

export GOPATH=/Users/ejiro/go

END
```